# Jackson produces invalid field names from Kotlin value classes

Tags: kotlin, jackson

When a Kotlin class has a property that is one of the new @JvmInline value classes, Jackson converts it to JSON with a weird suffix on the field name.

e.g.

```
@JvmInline
value class ModelName(val value: String)
```

```
data class MyDto(val modelName: ModelName)
```

Jackson will produce JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "modelName-11MJ8YI": "Some Model Name"
}
```

I've tried adding a @JsonProperty("modelName") annotation but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably, upgrading `jackson-module-kotlin` will solve this problem.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/356

If you can't upgrade, naming the `getter` as `@get:JvmName("getModelName")` should also solve the problem.

The reason for this problem is that the name of the method (`getter`) for the `value class` in `Kotlin` has a random suffix.

Comment: Yes, a schoolboy error on my part. Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading `jackson-module-kotlin` didn't fix it for me at first because I was using a custom `ObjectMapper`. I was able to fix it by creating an instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` (just in case someone stumbles on the same issue).